# How to allow the user to select a UIImagePickerController's source type?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

First let me tell you what I'm trying to do:

1. When the user clicks on a button, I want to present a `UIPopoverController` with a `UINavigationController` as its `contentViewController` (this is on an iPad)
2. The first `UIViewController` pushed into `UINavigationController` will be a custom view controller that has 2 buttons: "take picture" and "select from library".
3. Touching the "take picture" button will `setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` on the `UIImagePickerController` and push it into the `UINavigationController`
4. Touching the "select from library" button will `setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` on the `UIImagePickerController` and push it into the `UINavigationController`

I want to be able to do all of this and be able to allow a user to navigate backwards as the UINavigationController allows.

The problem is that since `UIImagePickerController` is also a `UINavigationController`, I cannot push it into another `UINavigationController` as stated in #3 and #4.

Questions:

1. Is there a way for me to use `UIImagePickerController` with a custom view controller pushed before the camera / photo library view controllers?
2. Or conversely, is there a way for me to get access to the camera / photo library view controllers to push them into a different `UINavigationController`?
3. Or is there another way that I am completely missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462893/showing-uiimagepickercontroller-in-uipopovercontroller-with-existing-uinavigatio)) was what finally solved this question for me.

Use the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method to access the navigationBar.

then with this code you can add a "cancel" button.

```
if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) {

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *top = bar.topItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imagePickerControllerDidCancel:)];
    [top setLeftBarButtonItem:cancel];

} else { 

    //do non imagePickerController things 

}
```