# Showing UIImagePickerController in UIPopoverController with existing UINavigationController (adding back button)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

So I have a `UIPopoverController` what houses my `UINavigationController` where I have my `UITableViewController` however one of my options on the `UITableView` is to go and select an image with the `UIImagePickerController`... Now on the iPhone I can simply use `presentModalViewController:animated:` however calling that from within a UIPopoverController causes a crash so thats not possible...

I also know the `UIImagePickerController` needs its own `UINavigationController` so I can't just push `pushViewController:animated:` either...

So I figured out that if I keep a link to the `UIPopoverController` I created, I can then use `setContentViewController:animated:` to switch to the UIImagePickerController's viewController...

However, I am now stuck at giving the user a way to go back to the previous `UINavigationController` as I need to be able to add a cancel button to the `UIImagePickerController` but when I try to do this the cancel button won't get added...

Heres my code that i'm using

```
-(void)doPhotoalbums {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [imagePicker setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];

        UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:nil];
        [imagePicker.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancel];

        //[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        [[self parentPopoverController] setContentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    } else {
        [UIAlertView showMessage:@"This device does not have any photo albums."];
    }
}
```

So my question is.. Does anybody know how I can get around this? either by adding a cancel/back button what I can hook up to make the navigationControllers switch back or another way to present this (i'd like to avoid switching between two UIPopoverControllers but I don't know what else I can do..

Thanks

Liam

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahh.. after a little break I found this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1710435?start=0&tstart=0

using the UINavigationControllerDelegate you can use the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method to access the navigationBar.. then with some code (below) you can add a button.

```
if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) {

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *top = bar.topItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imagePickerControllerDidCancel:)];
    [top setLeftBarButtonItem:cancel];

} else { 

    //do non imagePickerController things 

}
```